# How to filter based on "must not" object instead of "must"

Tags: rethinkdb

The filter function can accept an object as a way to define fields that must match. Is there an easy way to do the opposite? I want to filter down to items that must NOT match the provided object. I am aware of the .ne() function but that is an exact match. I'm currently doing a bunch of .and() and it gets a little ugly. I'm just looking for the magic to confirm [Issue #1000](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/1000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

````
```
r.table('posts').filter(function(post) {
  return post.merge({field1: value1, field2: value2}).ne(post)
})
```
````

Basically merge the post with the object you want to "match" against, and if that changes the value of `post` then include the post in the output.

Comment: This is exactly (close enough) what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't test if all three fields are different, but only if one is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `r.and` to make things a little better

```
r.table("posts").filter(function(post) {
    return r.and(
        post("field1").ne("value1),
        post("field2").ne("value2),
        post("field3").ne("value3)
    )
})
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I'm currently doing. I'll take this as confirmation that it is not possible to use an object instead of the code example you posted. Is the kind of ReQL sugar I'm looking for appropriate for RethinkDB to consider adding or is that better left to a community driver add-on?